# Rails: steps to take before deploying rails app (e.g. changing database to postgres, etc)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am about to deploy a rails app (onto heroku) I made and wanted to know what the procedure is. I know you have to change the database by changing `gem 'sqlite3'` to `gem 'pg'` but after I did that and went on my localhost:3000 it gives me the error:

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change gem. Database used in application on heroku default is postgres. Keep `gem 'sqlite3'` and add this in your Gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem "pg", "0.14.0"
end
```

Comment: Although it is suggested that you use the same database in development and production.

Comment: @sytycs ooo really? I thought sqlite was preferred in development because it was faster? would it make much of a difference? so you're saying for every project I should change sqlite3 to pg (if pg is my planned final database) in the beginning?

Comment: "We highly recommend using PostgreSQL during development. Maintaining parity between your development and deployment environments prevents subtle bugs from being introduced because of differences between your environments." [heroku.com](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3)

Comment: yeah, you should follow heroku's recommend, but before you can use pg gem in local development, you have to install postgresql database software.